# Styling the first occurence of text inside a div class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that contains some text and I would like to just sytle the Some Caption 1 text.

```html
<div class="pswp__caption__center">
 Some Caption 1
  <br>
  <small>Caption 2</small>
</div>
```

I have tried using first-child or first-type of css selector but it does not seem to work. I am also not able to change the HTML structure. Is it actually possible to achieve this?

Comment: What styles are you talking about though? Some props are inherited, some aren't, your css will have to change accordingly.

Comment: wrap `Some Caption 1` in a `span` and style it

Comment: I am not able to change the HTML

Answer (score 1):

```css
.pswp__caption__center {
  color: red;
}

small {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="pswp__caption__center">
 Some Caption 1
  <br>
  <small>Caption 2</small>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem, though, is that all children added to the div will be formatted in red unless a style is applied; pretty messy.

Answer (score 0):

**Style using JS**

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".pswp__caption__center");
const caption = container.querySelector("span");

caption.style.fontWeight = 800;
caption.style.color = "coral";
```

```html
<div class="pswp__caption__center">
  <span>Some Caption 1</span>
  <br>
  <small>Caption 2</small>
</div>
```

**Style using CSS**

```css
.pswp__caption__center span {
  color: coral;
  font - weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="pswp__caption__center">
  <span>Some Caption 1</span>
  <br>
  <small>Caption 2</small>
</div>
```

Comment: issue is I am not able to change the HTML structure

Comment: @user38208 what exactly you want to style?

Comment: Can you use JS and change `HTML`  and then style?

Comment: yes Can use JS. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

To put in my two-penneth, I believe you are abusing the tags, here, and should be looking at using semantically correct tags, like so...

```html
<div class="pswp__caption__center">
    <h3>My Centred Title</h3>
    <h4>My Smaller Sub-heading</h4>
</div>
```

The associated CSS would then be...

```css
.pswp__caption__center h3 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
}
.pswp__caption__center h4 {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}
```

Or perhaps you can use the `<figure>` tag...

```html
<figure class="pswp__caption__center">
    Some text or other.
    <figcaption>My figure text.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: issue is I am not able to change the HTML structure